# Creating a criterion that measures the F1 Loss

Tags: python, pytorch

I am currently creating criterion to measure the MSE loss function using:

```
loss_fcn = torch.nn.MSELoss() 

loss = loss_fcn(logits[getMaskForBatch(subgraph)], labels.float())
```

Now I need to change it to F1 score but I cannot seem to find one library that could be used for it

Comment: Why do you need to use F1 score?

Comment: I am calculating the F1 score for how well can my application classify faces @prosti

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/SuperShinyEyes/dcc68a08ff8b615442e3bc6a9b55a354)

Comment: or maybe this F1score function by scikit learn https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Comment: OK, but why F1 score? Why not accuracy?

Comment: because i want to consider False Positives and True Negatives in the equation @prosti

Comment: You normally would not to do that. This is complicated. The reason to use F1 score measure is is different, and I just wanted to check do you know when we use F1 score. Not a trick question.

Comment: well its from my dissertation titled "face recognition using graph neural networks" and i dont really know what is happening bro. I have two lists, one for predicted labels and one for actual labels

I get the FScore for that, but I think this line above is to optimize the network so that it would get the best FScore rather than best MSE score?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the reason to F1 score is if the targets are unbalanced, say 10 true, and 300 false. In case the dataset is almost nicely balanced we would use accuracy. MSE is not for classification, it is for regressioin.

Answer (score 1):

In particular, depending on the task you need to have a specific loss function.
Loss function also known as objective, cost or error function is somehow opposite to the optimization function. Loss function creates the loss, optimization function reduces the loss. :). These two functions should live in equilibrium so we don't overfit.

PyTorch Regression losses:

- `nn.L1Loss` L1 Loss (MAE)
- `nn.MSELoss` L2 Loss (MSE)
- `nn.SmoothL1Loss` Huber

PyTorch Classification losses:

- `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`
- `nn.KLDivLoss`
- `nn.NLLLoss`

PyTorch GAN training

- `nn.MarginRankingLoss`

So if you used `nn.MSELoss` you probably need to stay with regression, because F1  is a classification metric.

If you really need F1 score for some other reason, you may use [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#from-binary-to-multiclass-and-multilabel).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that?

F1 score is usually an evaluation metrics not a loss function. Moreover, to use F1 score as a loss function you have to ensure that it's differentiable and convex (which I think probably is not the case otherwise it would already be in the literature).

There're many loss functions that could sweet with your problem like crossentropy, negative log likelyhood, CTC loss, etc.

Comment: because my lecturer told me to implement F1 score evaluation which i have done, i just need to optimize my model using f1 score rather than MSE loss

Comment: As you say, the F1 score is for evaluation. If you problem is a classification one, you don't have to use MSE loss; rather try one of those listed above. If your problem is a regression one, you cannot evaluate the model with F1 score. You should use R2 or MAPE.